# Automatically Register Custom Models in Azure ML Studio Designer and Deploy Within Designer

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, mlops, azure-ml-pipelines

I am currently trying out different architectures with Azure ML Ecosystem.
Currently, I am testing out Azure ML Studio Designer.

I want to create a complete End to End ML system, where I train several models and deploy the best.

The Pipeline Created:
[image]

In the Designer, is it possible to register a custom-trained model(it will appear in the model assets in the workspace)? Also is it possible to directly deploy the best model within the Designer?

Not manually clicking on the job and Registering and Deploying but in a more automated way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to create the designer manually and assign the deployment manually for the first time. Input for the next iteration will be the web service input. For that we need to get the web service output to be attached with the evaluation model metrics. For the next time it will be running in repeated state.

Follow the steps to make the automation for the case of designer deployment from the designer itself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above images are not being connected to the web service input for the automation.

[image]

The above image will be taking the result of automation of the web service to perform the continuous deployment.

Connect to the compute target.

[image]

[image]

Create new pipeline job

To deploy we need to have an inference cluster. It will be AKS by default.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

We will get the inference pipeline like above. Get the details of the web service endpoint and deploy it with the web service. First time have to do it manually, next time it will work automatically.

[image]

Above is the total structure will look like in designer for automation of the deployment.

Comment: By doing so are the Models versioned and shown under Models Assets in the studio?

Comment: Versions will be shown. For every execution. But it can get manually. not automatically.

Comment: When I try to generate the Inference Pipeline it says I need to select only one model. Does that mean in the designer we cant select the best model and deploy it automatically, is it?

Comment: For example I gave linear regression as one model. Multimodel classification options need to be replaced in the design. It will function accordingly. then we can get the different results and then can get the best model. but every result we get will be deployed automatically. not only the best model. If we need the best model, we need to check the evaluation metrics of the models and take MAX operation, then separate the required model from the list and deploy. It's too complex to execute. But the success rate is low.